# scanning compressed files with mcafee command line virusscan for linux is slow

Tags: virus-scanning, mcafee

Using McAfee 64-bit command line virusscan 6.0.4 for linux. It is taking 4 hours to scan 17 files many of which are compressed (zip, tar, ova, etc). I have tried increasing cache size, number of threads. Nothing seems to improve the performance.

Anyone encounter this and how did you run the scanner to improve performance?

Comment: what information do you get about the system's activity from tools like top, sar and iotop?